# this is undefined outside from constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created an Express REST API using Dependency Injection with Inversify. I have a basic controller class

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import { injectable, inject } from 'inversify';

import { IUserController } from './IUserController';
import { AppEntity } from '../../enterpriseBusinessRules/entities/AppEntity';
import { UserEntity } from '../../enterpriseBusinessRules/entities/UserEntity';
import { GroupEntity } from '../../enterpriseBusinessRules/entities/GroupEntity';
import { IUserUseCases } from '../../applicationBusinessRules/useCases/IUserUseCases';
import { IOCTypes } from '../../iOC/IOCTypes';

@injectable()
export class UserController implements IUserController {
    public userUseCases: IUserUseCases;

    constructor(@inject(IOCTypes.IUserUseCases) userUseCases: IUserUseCases) { 
        this.userUseCases = userUseCases;
    }

    public async fetchUsers(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void>{
        try {
            const users: UserEntity[] = await this.userUseCases.fetchUsers(request);

            response.status(200).json({
                message: 'Users were fetched.',
                users,
            });
        } catch (error) {
            next(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever I request the route `/users` the function `fetchUsers` gets executed. Unforunately my API crashes and throws this error

> RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code:
>   undefined

I debugged and found this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'userUseCases' of undefined

Within the constructor of the class `this` is set and works fine. Within the `fetchUsers` function `this` is `undefined`. How can I fix this? Because I have to use `this` to get access to my `userUseCases` variable.

---

**Edit:** Thanks to Adam Kosmalas comment I was able to fix it by binding the function within the constructor

```
this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this)
```

but I don't know if this is the best solution. Then I would have to bind every function in every class within its constructor...

Any other ideas?

Comment: Put `super()` in a `constructor`

Comment: sorry I can't because I'm not extending a class, I'm just implementing an Interface

Comment: have you tried binding your `fetchUsers` method in the constructor, like this: `this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this)`?

Comment: hm that worked. but why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another options is to use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Arrow_functions_used_as_methods) for method declarations. This way you don't need to explicitly bind `this`:

```
public fetchUsers = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
      const users: UserEntity[] = await this.userUseCases.fetchUsers(request);

      response.status(200).json({
        message: 'Users were fetched.',
        users,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thank! save me almost an hour :D

Answer (score 1):

Inside the constructor bind "this" to your function using `bind(this)` this will make sure It will execute the function in context of "this" of the class.

```
constructor(@inject(IOCTypes.IUserUseCases) userUseCases: IUserUseCases) { 
        this.userUseCases = userUseCases;
        this.fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this)
    }
```

It was not working because your function was executing somewhere else thus it was getting 'this' from there

If you don't want to bind and properties are public then you can directly access if from outside of the service like.

`const users: UserEntity[] = await this.nameOfTheImportedService.userUseCases.fetchUsers(request);`

Comment: Is there another solution to get access to the class variables without using `this` ?

Comment: yes if your variables are public you directly access them there in the component you are injecting the service to by using this of that component.

Comment: @hrp8sfH4xQ4 I will add it to answer

Comment: that would be cool. I think Claritys solution fits better but maybe yours will help others